# Retrive the value from the object where value of key is pointing to different object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Lets say I have a object

```
obj1 : {
  "a" : 22
  "b" : 33
  "c" : 67
}
```

and obj2 as

```
obj2 : {
  x:"obj1.a" (string - path)
  y: "obj1.b" (string- path)
}
```

but when i do obj2.x I get obj1.a which is correct but I want 22, How do I do this? Or is there any npm package which takes care of this?

Comment: why not take the reference without using strings, like `obj1.a`?

Comment: ah, so u want 1 object to reference data in another object? use `Object.defineProperty` with `get` logic

Comment: actually, chinmay tell me if it answers your question, if not THEN I'll flag

Comment: @TheBombSquad Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can use `get` logic when defining your object in order to achieve this.. basically `get` would call a function when the key is accessed and the value would be what that function returns

```js
let obj1={
  "a" : 22,
  "b" : 33,
  "c" : 67
}

let obj2={
  get x(){
    return obj1.a
  },
  get y(){
    return obj1.b
  }
}

console.log([obj2.x,obj2.y]) //[22,33]
obj1.a++; obj1.b++ //changing obj1 to prove that it obj2 will change when obj 1 changes
console.log([obj2.x,obj2.y]) //[23,34]
```